# Java or Scala maven installed jar using CLASSPATH

Tags: java, scala, maven, classpath

Finding maven with pom.xml files confusing.

Dependencies can be added to the pom file which can be installed using the following command:

```sh
mvn dependency:resolve
```

The result is, by default, dependencies installed into the .m2 directory with the caller's home directory.

Each maven package might have one or more of its own dependencies each having a jar file.

After the installation, you'll end up with many packages installed beyond the jars defined as dependencies in the pom file.

I want to import jars in applications using the CLASSPATH environment variable; however, it seems that including just the jar of a dependency defined in my pom file will leave out its own dependencies.

Having trouble understanding the scope of a dependency jar and how to make those dependencies available to applications using the CLASSPATH environment variable.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please be aware that almost no normal Java application uses the `CLASSPATH` environment variable (and if they do, it is generally customized for a specific application run), because otherwise you would run into conflicts for dependencies between different applications (eg different library versions, conflicting/incompatible dependencies, etc). It is better to get out of this habit and use the standard ways of dealing with this.

Answer (score 1):

Maven dependency plugin can be used to get the classpath as explained [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:build-classpath).

This would print the classpath in the console:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

or classpath can be written to a file:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
```

Output from these commands can be used to setup your CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: so the jars don't include their own dependencies in the archive? they aren't independent?

Comment: Jars usually don't include other dependency jars within them but there are other packaging options that can bundle everything in one jar. The commands shown here would print all the dependencies declared in your pom and their dependencies so you  get the complete classpath.